# WP API Comments: posting a comment containing emojis?

Tags: wordpress, emoji, wp-api

I'm having an issue on a React Native / WP API mobile app.

I want to use WP Comments via WP API to post comments on news.

Everything works fine, except the emojis part. I can POST request with text, emoticons (smileys), but when I try to post a comment with emojis (let's say the comment `content` is " super comment:  " - iOs emojis), my request returns an error: `rest_comment_failed_create`, with status `500`.

I did the same directly into WP Admin (added a comment with this content: it creates a new comment with an empty content).

I guess emojis are not implemented right now on my WP installation, but is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The database, or more precisely the fields in which emojis are stored, must have compatible encoding, for example `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`